# Protecting copy constructor with std::enable_if

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, template-meta-programming, type-traits

I've written a class to facilitate type erasure that has the following constructors:

```
class Envelope {
public:
    Envelope() {}

    template<typename Runnable>
    Envelope(Runnable runnable)
        : m_runFunc(&Envelope::RunAndDeleteRunnable<Runnable>), m_runnable(new Runnable(runnable)) {
    }

    template<typename Runnable>
    Envelope(Runnable * runnable)
        : m_runFunc(&Envelope::RunRunnable<Runnable>), m_runnable(runnable) {
    }
};
```

I want to rewrite the first non-default constructor to take a reference rather than a value (`Runnable & runnable` rather than `Runnable runnable`), but if I do that then copying with a non-const `Envelope` like so

```
Envelope next(...);
Envelope otherNext(next);
```

invokes that constructor rather than the copy constructor, and I get a stack overflow.

I think I can prevent that constructor from being called when `Runnable` == `Envelope` with `std::enable_if` like so

```
template<typename Runnable = typename std::enable_if<std::negate<std::is_same<Runnable, Nova::Envelope>>::value, Runnable>::type>
Envelope(Runnable & runnable)
    : m_runFunc(&Envelope::RunAndDeleteRunnable<Runnable>), m_runnable(new Runnable(runnable)) {
}
```

and it compiles fine (although it triggers some intellisense errors in Visual Studio 2015, which is mildly annoying), but it doesn't stop that constructor from being called with non-const `Envelope`s and triggering a stack overflow.

I'm not entirely sure what I'm doing wrong here.

Comment: `std::negate` is unary `-`, not unary `!`. This means that it's not really doing anything at all, since it's changing 1 to -1 (which is still truthy), and doesn't change zero. You probably meant `std::enable_if<!std::is_same<Runnable, Nova::Envelope>::value, Runnable>::type>`

Comment: @cdhowie That's probably worthy of an answer, IMO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
template<
  class Runnable,
  std::enable_if_t<
    !std::is_same<std::decay_t<Runnable>, Envelope>{},
    int
  > =0
>
Envelope(Runnable&& runnable) : 
  m_runFunc(&Envelope::RunAndDeleteRunnable<std::decay_t<Runnable>>),
  m_runnable(new std::decay_t<Runnable>(std::forward<Runnable>(runnable)))
{}
```

I did use C++14 style `_t` variants of some traits; if you are stuck in C++11, simply write your own helpers, the `typename` spam is not worth having in client code.

This is a perfect forwarding constructor.  It consumes anything that isn't an `Envelope` by forwarding reference.

We use `std::decay_t` to generate a "storable" version of the `Runnable` type, and perfect forward the `Runnable&&` into it.

Another change I'd make is replace the `new` call with `std::make_unique` as part of a general policy to not raw-new raw pointers.

[Live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d6d2abe93becf3c2).

Comment: Are you sure this is syntactically correct? I can't get it to compile.

Comment: @nzerbzer Live example running on g++ added.

Comment: Thanks. Using a `unique_ptr` is a good idea, but this class has to be able to hold objects it doesn't own as well, so I don't know if it would fit.

Comment: @nzerbzer I see.  :)  You could use a `unique_ptr<T, void(*)(T*)>` for that purpose.  Or a `unique_ptr<T, maybe_delete<T>>`.  My argument would be to avoid writing business logic and resource management in the same type.

Answer (score 5):

The easiest way to prevent this is to add a "non const" copy constructor:

```
class Envelope {
public:
    Envelope() {}
    Envelope(const Envelope&) = default;
    Envelope(Envelope& e) : Envelope(const_cast<const Envelope&>(e)) {}
    ...
    }
};
```

You're not doing anything in particular wrong, it's just that when you write constructors that take one templated parameter (or a variadic number), they tend to be "sticky" and intercept things intended for the copy constructor. The copy constructor does not get any special treatment that I'm aware of when it comes to selecting which function gets called. The templated functions are simply a better match for a non-const object. By adding a concrete (non-template) that matches the non-const case, there will now be a tie in goodness-of-match between that function and the template. And in cases of a tie a function always beats out a template.

Comment: I've copied those constructors verbatim both into my Envelope class and a fresh class with no other members, and both give me `error C2580: multiple versions of a defaulted special member functions are not allowed`.

Comment: @nzerbzer You either pasted the code incorrectly or your compiler has a bug: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d820b7dc64e549c2.

Comment: Looks like it's a bug in MSVC2015 then :(

Answer (score 3):

I suppose you can write something like

```
template <typename Runnable,
          typename = typename std::enable_if<
             false == std::is_same<Runnable, Nova::Envelope>::value
          >::type>
Envelope (Runnable const & runnable)
    : m_runFunc(&Envelope::RunAndDeleteRunnable<Runnable>),
      m_runnable(new Runnable(runnable))
 { }
```

**-- EDIT --**

As pointed by W.F. (thanks), it's better the following solution

```
template <typename Runnable,
          typename std::enable_if<
             false == std::is_same<Runnable, Nova::Envelope>::value
          >::type * = nullptr>
Envelope (Runnable const & runnable)
    : m_runFunc(&Envelope::RunAndDeleteRunnable<Runnable>),
      m_runnable(new Runnable(runnable))
 { }
```

because if you need two (or more) template constructor, they can't differ only for a default template type parameter; the W.F.'s solution avoid this problem.

Comment: @W.F. - ehmm... your way should also work but... please, can you explain (an example?) what you mean with "may have a problem with triggering out unmatched condition"?

Comment: @W.F. - you're right; thanks. Not sure to understand the reason; modified my answer; do you think that is correct my explain?

Comment: Yup I think reason you pointed is ok. PS. My nick is more W.F. not W.C. :)

Comment: @W.F. - D'oh! Sorry.

Comment: Aaargh! Yoda Conditionals. My eyes. Especially unnecessary when a simple `!` would suffice.